# ¿3 estamentos if seguidos con condiciones parecidas? php

Tags: php

No consigo sacar este quebradero de cabeza, necesito que se cumpla una condición:

```
if($a == null):
    <div class="imagen1">
        <img src="http://www.juguetessomosnosotros.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/rubik_cubemess.png">
    </div>
endif;

if($b == null):
    <div class="imagen2">
        <img src="otra imagen">
    </div>
endif;
if($b == null and $a == null):
    <div class="imagen" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="imagen2" style="display: none;"></div>
endif;
```

Pero se me siguen mostrando las primeras imágenes cuando yo quiero que no se muestren si la última condición se cumple.

Quiero que si la primera es `null` que muestra una imagen, que si la segunda es `null` que muestre otra, pero si ,las dos son `null` al mismo tiempo que no muestre ninguna.

Comment: Si la última no se muestra entonces es que ninguna de las dos es null. Porque no haces un echo delas dos para ver su valor

Comment: Que diferencia habria entre que `a` sea igual a `b` o que `b` sea igual a `a`. No es que los dos primeros `if` sean parecidos, son iguales. Puedes mostrar el momento en el que asignas valores a las variables?

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper si que son null porque las primeras condiciones se cumplen y muestra la imagen indicada

Comment: Eso no tiene nada que ver, las dos pueden ser iguales y ser null @AlbertoMartínez

Comment: @AndoniAlda actualizada pregunta, fallo al expresar el código, el valor de las variables viene dado por una base de datos

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper editada la pregunta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba con esto, tenias mal concatenados los if

```
<?php 
if($b == null and $a == null) {
    ?>
    <div class="imagen" style="display: none;">
        <img src="otra imagen">
    </div>
    <div class="imagen2" style="display: none;">
        <img src="otra imagen">
    </div>
    <?php
}
else {
    if($a == null) {
        ?>
        <div class="imagen1">
            <img src="http://www.juguetessomosnosotros.com/wp-
                      content/uploads/2012/08/rubik_cubemess.png">
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    if($b == null) {
        ?>
        <div class="imagen2">
            <img src="otra imagen">
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias, esto ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Prueba anidando los ifs:

```
<?php if($a == null) {?>

   <?php if ($b==null) {?>
      <div class="imagen">
        <img src="otra imagen" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="imagen2" style="display: none;">
        <img src="otra imagen">
    </div>
   <?php } else { ?>
     <div class="imagen1">
        <img src="http://www.juguetessomosnosotros.com/wp-
                  content/uploads/2012/08/rubik_cubemess.png">
    </div>
   <?php } ?>
<?php } else if ($b == null) {?>
   <div class="imagen2">
        <img src="otra imagen">
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Asi diferencias cuando se cumplen ambas condiciones o solo una.

Comment: He anidado los ifs pero me sigue mostrando las imagenes, es decir si a es null me muestra una imagen, si b es null me muestra otra, pero los dos null me muestra las dos imagenes, no consigo que funcione con este códgio que has puesto

Comment: Perdona, se me olvidó un if dentro del primer caso y si las dos eran null mostraba la figura 1, ya está editado. A mi me funciona bien, no debería mostrarte las dos figuras por el display:none, si aun las muestra puede ser un problema de css.